# Location of Route 1, Grants Pass, Oregon USA

Tags: united-states, 1940s, address, oregon

I am trying to find the location of the addresses: R.F.D 1, Grants Pass (1934-1944) and Rt 1, Box 413 Grants Pass (1946). My great-grandmother and her husband, Thomas Albert Bird, lived in Grants Pass from 1922 until they died in 1949 and 1955. T A Bird grew "fine glads, bulbous iris and carnations" on his property called Bird's Glad Acre. I have determined that R F D means Rural Free Delivery and assume that the '1' in the address is Route 1. Where would Rt 1 have been located?

Comment: A RFD route consists of all the locations for mail delivery assigned to single (daily) carrier. Depending on the population density, it can cover A LOT of ground. It also can change over time. Best guess would be to contact the US Mail in Grants Pass, to narrow down the general direction. (The post office in my home town had a map posted with all the routes). Or check land records in Josephine County, Oregon.

Comment: Have you checked census records for 1940 and 1930? There might be a street name there.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the 1930 and 1940 US Census. The addresses listed are within the town area of Grants Pass. I am now of the opinion that Thomas and Annie Bird owned two properties - one in Grants Pass and the other 'out of town' on Rt 1.. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: In my search of land records, I have received information from the Josephine County Assessor (Connie Roach) that Thomas Bird purchased two adjoining blocks on NW Manganata, Grants Pass in June 1929 from Mabel F Russell and F W Russell. This affirms my previous post that T A Bird owned two properties, one out of town and one within Grants Pass. It is interesting to note that the area around Manangata was originally designated as 'Lincoln Park addition to the town, now city of Grants Pass'.